# Is there a full "research tree" for all of the upgrades possible for gear, items, and housing?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Similar to XCOM 2 and it's ridiculously crazy research tree, is there a flowchart guide as to what possible upgrades there are in the game, and how to go about getting them?

For instance, there are some which I don't know the full extent of how it upgrades, but at least have a partial idea:

- Housing

  - Tent (Free) -> Pay off 5,000 Mile debt to Tom, -> House (98k Bells) -> ???
- Tools

  - Flimsy Tools -> Pay off 5,000 Mile debt to Tom -> Unlock Nook Miles+ -> Redeem 3000 Nook Miles for "Pretty Good Tools" kit -> ???
- Quality of Life

  - Pay off 5,000 Mile debt to Tom -> Unlock Nook Miles+ -> Redeem 800 Nook Miles for "Tool Ring" -> ???
- Inventory

  - Pay off 5,000 Mile debt to Tom -> Unlock Nook Miles+ -> Redeem 5000 Nook Miles for "Bigger Pockets" -> ???

Comment: Well, I guess I can cross 'making a link between XCOM and Animal Crossing' on my list of 'things I tought I would never hear'.

Comment: There's a 2nd inventory upgrade I got for 8000 now I have 4 rows

Comment: [I mean...](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1191623-animal-crossing)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not a tree—it's single-path, though not necessarily sequential for the tools.

House upgrades

- Tent (5k miles)
- House and storage feature (98k bells)
- Larger floor plan (198k bells)
- Room in back of house (348k bells)
- Larger house and external decorations (548k bells)
- Rooms on left and right of first floor (758k bells)
- Second floor (1.2m bells)
- Basement (2.5m bells)

Tools

- Flimsy (through story)
- Regular (through story)
- Colorful/Outdoorsy (customized) in upgraded Nook's Cranny
- Golden ([see requirements](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/25/21192477/golden-tools-requirements-axe-fishing-rod-net-shovel-slingshot-watering-can))

To my knowledge, as of now there are no further "quality of life" or inventory upgrades.

Comment: Are there upgrades to things like haircuts, tool ring, etc.?  Like vaulting pole -> ladder -> ???

Comment: @senpai the vaulting pole and ladder are separate and have no upgrades

Comment: Are the Colorful/Outdoorsy tools considered upgrades or sidegrades to the Regular tools?

Comment: There are also golden tools according to Polygon - https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/25/21192477/golden-tools-requirements-axe-fishing-rod-net-shovel-slingshot-watering-can

Comment: @senpai Colorful/Outdoorsy are not unlocked until later but have the same durability as regular tools